# Shiny silent validate in observeEvent?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a `validate` statement within an `observeEvent` section of my shiny app but when the condition isn't met no error message is returned.  It just remains a blank screen.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("test"),
      sidebarPanel(
        p("Demo Page."),
        sliderInput("sldr", "Select a value", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
        actionButton("btn", "Push Me!")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("text")
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){

      observeEvent(input$btn, {

        validate(
          need(input$sldr > 5, "Require > 5")
        )

        output$text <- renderText({
          "hello world"
        })
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Right now, when I start up the app and push the `Push Me!` action button nothing happens at all (the `validate` is stopping the processing) but no error message is returned, just a white screen.  If I change the selected value to `6` then it proceeds and prints the message.

Why is the `validate` not getting displayed?

Comment: I answered, but I think you are at least as familiar with Shiny as I am :).

Answer (score 3):

I guess because `observeEvent` has no where to send the message to. Pushing the validate inside the print works the way you want it to and makes more sense to me.

But it might not be exactly what you need. Not sure if the entire `observeEvent` command is terminated for example.

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("test"),
      sidebarPanel(
        p("Demo Page."),
        sliderInput("sldr","Select a value",min = 0,max = 10,value = 5),
        actionButton("btn","Push Me!")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("text")
      )
    ),
    server = function(input,output) {

      observeEvent(input$btn,{

        output$text <- renderText({
          validate(
            need(input$sldr > 5,"Require > 5")
          )
          "hello world"
        })
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... that appears to be the case.  It works in this instance but complicates things when there is some preprocessing to make an object that will be used in multiple render statements.  I wouldn't want the same error printed multiple times nor have additional unexplained errors.  Thanks for idea but perhaps there is a better solution for `observeEvent`?

Comment: Just do it with plain old `if` logic? Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish, but thanks for the vote.